# When onsettings event get fired

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

The documentation as to when onsettings [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701593.aspx) is fired describes as following

> Occurs when app settings are changed.

Does it mean this event is fired every time a control used on settings pane is changed? It seem to me this event is fired every time I hit Win+I to bring up the Settings charm. I have created some views on my page for Settings and when I change a value (e.g., for a toggle switch) then appropriate event is fired for that control. Can someone please clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That text looks rather like default boilerplate for an "onXXX" event, and it's definitely confusing, but the context of the samples should steer you in the right direction.  "when app settings are *requested*" would be more accurate, IMHO.

The event fires when there's a request made for the Settings charm, and your code would need to [set up the appropriate command on the Settings flyout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780611.aspx). It's not going to save anything on your behalf, and in fact, the [the reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj856914.aspx) is a good overview of what you'd need to do to save the settings changes automatically - essentially leveraging onChange events of the various controls you're using inside of the flyouts.

Comment: Thanks for your help. At least I am not the only one finding this documentation a bit confusing. Your links are really helpful.